# ensuring unique email address with django-social-auth

Tags: django

I was looking around the documentation for django-social-auth but I can't seem to find a setting that will enforce unique emails for user accounts.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: what do you mean ? 2 accounts with 1 email ? or an account with several emails ?

Comment: I created an account through the regular django-auth system, then used social-auth with facebook and another account was created, so two user accounts have email example@ex.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have unique emails with python social auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273904/how-to-have-unique-emails-with-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer can be found in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273904/how-to-have-unique-emails-with-python-social-auth).

It says to put another step in  edit the SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE. I believe this this is a simpler solution.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing to do is subclass the `UserManager` class, and overwrite its `create_user` method to check that there isn't a `User` instance with that email address in the database (`django-social-auth` uses `create_user` to...create users on registration).  A bit more on how to set this up is on the [Configuration](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) page of the `django-social-auth` docs. You'll then need to subclass `User` as well, so that you can associate the custom manager with it. More on [model Managers from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers).