# How to have unique emails with Python social auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-socialauth

I'm using Python Social Auth (Django) with Google and Facebook and it creates different users with the same email. How do I fix that?

If I log first with Google, logout, and then with Facebook, it must just associate the accounts and not create.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some code reading I found this in the pipeline:

```
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
```

So, I just added it before

```
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
```

And it worked.

Comment: Note to readers: there's a documented privacy concern here, which is why the default setting is off.  In short: you're depending on the security of email validation at each of the third party auth providers.

Comment: Do you have to be logged in? It seems if you are not logged in, it creates a new account.